# Github ERROR: Repository not found (yes, another one)

Tags: git, github

I've searched and read most of the similar issues here on SO and none seem to be the same as mine.  I have a private repos on Github and an hour ago I was able to push just fine.  Now, I get the ERROR: Repository not found message.

I have the following in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host github
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gr.pub
```

because I need to use a specific public key. My .git/config looks like the following (with some info change for security purposes:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@github:MyProject/MyProject.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

I don't understand why it worked for a while then just stopped.

EDIT: Now, I can't even clone it.  I get the same error.

EDIT 2: I added VERBOSE to my ssh config and this is what I get:

```
Authenticated to github.com ([207.97.227.239]:22).
ERROR: Repository not found.
Transferred: sent 2432, received 2920 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12278.1, received 14741.7
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

EDIT 3: More information, I ran ssh -vT git@github and here is the relevant information:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/gdboling/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for gh
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/gdboling/.ssh/id_rsa_gr type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/gdboling/.ssh/id_rsa_gr-cert type -1
....
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/gdboling/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note it is finding the right key, then using the wrong one.

Comment: None of the other researched issues were working for me either, but this helped me track down the issue (also a key problem).  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your SSH agent is offering up the wrong key when trying to authenticate you. This issue over at superuser sounds like what you're trying to do https://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you stop paying for your account?

Can you flip verbose on in .ssh/config ?

Comment: No, I did not stop paying.  I edited my question to add the VERBOSE output.