# How exactly (step-by-step) to clone my git project

Tags: git, clone

I have read other questions like this and cannot apply it to my situation. I am very new to using github too, so maybe need the simplest explanation. I have a project called JS_project. The folder (and it's contents) have already been committed to Github. I simply want to clone this folder/project as recommended by Github instructions on how to use Github.

I tried to type this into Terminal, in my JS-project directory, and it gave me an error (after I hit enter after the 1st line):

```
git clone git@github.com:JS_project_copy.
Cloning into 'JS_project_copy.'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I just don't know what this means. I of course have access to my own file, but maybe I do not understand the error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: the error is telling you that git@github.com:JS_project_copy. is not a valid git repository location

Comment: Just for cloning a repository to your computer you don't necessarily need to use SSH. If the repository is public, you can simply try something like `git clone https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish.git`.Basically, just use the https URL of the repository. Read [GitHub Bootcamp](https://help.github.com/categories/54/articles)

Comment: @pallandt: SSH is not the issue here. The URL is just wrong -- copying the URL from the repo's page on github will prevent that.

Comment: @Nevik Rehnel I meant to say it's not necessary to use SSH in all cases, and that she could clone that repo in a more simple manner; and yes, copying the URL from the repo's page is highly recommended. Given your comment though, I re-read the original question and I think she probably did have the wrong URL.

Comment: @cdbitesky [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) is not even a question, therefore this question is not a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Noni please update your question with which GitHub instructions you were following. Is your repo public? If it is, is it ok for you to give us a link to your repo?

Comment: possible duplicate [Github ERROR: Repository not found (yes, another one)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629840/github-error-repository-not-found-yes-another-one).

Comment: thanks @pallandt! sorry for the delayed response, haven't been here in a while. but your suggestion worked, it was very easy in fact. i typed "git clone" + "my github project URL" and that made a clone right away. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that it can not find the repository you specified. 
There really isn't a step by step for cloning, because cloning is just
a single command `git clone urlToProjectYouWantToClone`
Consider reading some guides like [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)

Comment: thanks Bill! i did get the http:// from my github project, and typed "git clone" then pasted "my URL of my git repo" into Terminal on my mac and that cloned it right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you really did enter the command you mentioned verbatim, then you are simply using a wrong URL format.

Github SSH repo URLs have the format `git@github.com:<repo-owner>/<repo-name>.git`

Every repo page on Github also offers you the main URL forms for copy&paste. It is recommended that you use the URLs from there.

See this image if you cannot find the URL box on the repo page:
[image: Repo URL box location]